# JavaFx. How to resume?

Tags: java, javafx

I am writing a timeline for text:

Usage:

```
Text text = new Text();
......
group.getChildren().addAll(text);
    root.getChildren().addAll(group);

tl.play();
```

This works fine. If I want to pause and continue the animation, `tl.pause();` and `tl.play();` can do that.

Now, I want to make the animation restart from the beginning and I use `tl.stop();` and `tl.playFromStart();` But the effect of this combination is as same as the effect of `tl.pause();` & `tl.play();`.

My question is, why does tl.playFromStart(); not work properly and how to resume animation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How `Timeline`s Work**

A [`Timeline`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) represents a period of time over which an animation is performed. The `Timeline` comprises of a collection of [`KeyFrame`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html). Each [`KeyFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html#KeyFrame-javafx.util.Duration-javafx.event.EventHandler-javafx.animation.KeyValue...-)

- *must* specify a point in time on the `Timeline` (the `Duration` object you pass in)
- *may* optionally also specify a collection of [`KeyValue`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyValue.html), which
  comprise `WritableValue`s (for example, `Property`s) and target
  values for those `WritableValue`s at that timepoint
- *may* optionally specify an action to be performed, in the form of an
  `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`

The `Timeline` has a [`currentTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#currentTimeProperty) property, which (of course) progresses forward as time elapses while the `Timeline` is playing. `pause()` will stop the progression of the `currentTime`, leaving it fixed at its current value. `stop()` will stop the progression of the `currentTime` and sets the `currentTime` back to zero.

If the `Timeline` has `KeyFrame`s that specify `KeyValue`s, then as the `currentTime` changes, the `WritableValue`s specified in the `KeyValue`s will be set to values depending on the `currentTime`. (Specifically, if the `WritableValue`s are interpolatable, the value will be interpolated between two adjacent `KeyFrames` specifying `KeyValue`s for that `WritableValue`. Otherwise the value will just be set to the "most recent" `KeyFrame` specifying a value for that `WritableValue`.)

If the `Timeline` has `KeyFrame`s that specify actions (`EventHandler<ActionEvent>`s), then as the `currentTime` progresses past the time specified by that `KeyFrame`, the action is invoked.

**Why your code doesn't work with `stop()` or `playFromStart()`**

In your case, your `KeyFrame` specifies an action, which adds new transforms to the node's list of transforms. Note that this does not depend on the `currentTime` at all, except that every time the `currentTime` reaches `0.04 seconds`, a new transform is added (plus, whatever method `shiftAndScale` whose implementation you didn't show does). Thus if you `stop()` the timeline, the `currentTime` gets reset to zero, but nothing happens to the node because of this. (Indeed, the `currentTime` only varies between `0` and `0.04` seconds anyway.)

**Other problems with your code**

There is a problem with your code, in that you have a memory leak. A `Node` maintains an `ObservableList` of `Transform`s. You are adding to this list (quite frequently), but never removing anything. The `Node` is quite intelligent: it keeps a hidden matrix which is the net effect of all the transforms; when you add a new transform it stores it in the list and then updates the "net" matrix with a simple matrix multiplication. Hence you won't see any computational performance problems here: it scales fine from that perspective. However, it does store all the individual transforms (because, for example, it supports removing them later), and so if you let this run long enough you will *eventually* run out of memory.

The one other (maybe minor) issue with your code is that you are doing a lot of floating point arithmetic when you combine all these transforms. Any rounding errors will eventually accumulate. You should try to find a technique that avoids accumulation of rounding errors.

**Ways to fix your code**

To fix this, you have a couple of options:

If the animation is "naturally cyclical" (meaning it returns to its starting state after some fixed time, like a rotation), then just define the `Timeline` in terms of that natural duration. Using just your rotation as a simple example, you could do:

```
double secondsPerCompleteCycle = (360.0 / 0.75) * 0.04 ;
Rotate rotation = new Rotate(0, new Point3D(1, 0, 0));
group.getTransforms().add(rotation);
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(secondsPerCompleteCycle), 
    new KeyValue(rotation.angleProperty(), 360, Interpolator.LINEAR)));
timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
timeline.play();
```

Now `timeline.stop()` will set the `currentTime` to zero, which will have the effect of setting the angle of the rotation back to its initial value (also zero).

If the animation is not naturally repetitive, I would use a (integer type) counter to keep track of the "current frame" in whatever time units you choose, and then bind values of the transform to the counter. Using the same example, you could do

```
double degreesPerFrame = 0.75 ;
LongProperty frameCount = new SimpleLongProperty();
Rotate rotation = new Rotate(0, new Point3D(1, 0, 0));
group.getTransforms().add(rotation);
rotation.angleProperty().bind(frameCount.multiply(degreesPerFrame));

Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.04), e -> 
    frameCount.set(frameCount.get() + 1)));
timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
timeline.play();

// to reset to the beginning:
timeline.stop();
frameCount.set(0L);
```

You could also consider using an [`AnimationTimer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html), depending on your exact requirements. I would try one of these techniques first, though.

In your case the algebra gets quite complex (prohibitively complex, for me at any rate). Each action adds three transforms to the node; a translation, a scale, and a rotation about the x-axis. The 4x4 matrix representations of these are:

```
1 0 0 tx
0 1 0 ty
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
```

for the translation,

```
sx  0 0 0 
 0 sy 0 0
 0  0 1 0
 0  0 0 1
```

for the scale, and

```
1      0       0 0
0 cos(t) -sin(t) 0
0 sin(t)  cos(t) 0
0      0       0 1
```

for the rotation.

While it's not too hard to compute the net effect of these three (just multiply them together), computing the net matrix you get from applying these an arbitrary number of times is beyond me (perhaps...). Additionally, the amount you are translating in the x direction is changing, which makes it pretty much impossible.

So the other way to approach this is to define a single transform and apply it to the node, then modify it on each event. This would look like

```
Affine transform = new Affine() ; // creates identity transform
node.getTransforms().add(transform);

Timeline timeline = new Timeline(Duration.seconds(0.04), event -> {
    double shiftX = ... ;
    double shiftY = ... ;
    double scaleX = ... ;
    double scaleY = ... ;
    double angle = 0.75 ;
    Affine change = new Affine();
    change.append(new Translate(shiftX, shiftY));
    change.append(new Scale(scaleX, scaleY));
    change.append(new Rotate(angle, new Point3D(1, 0, 0)));
    transform.append(change);
});

timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
timeline.play();
```

As described above, `stop()` and `pause()` will have (almost) the same effect. (The only difference is the time to the first new update when you play again, for `stop()` it will be 0.04 seconds, for `pause()` it will be less - whatever remained until the next update when it was paused.) But to "reset" the animation, you just do

```
timeline.stop();
transform.setToIdentity(); // resets to beginning
```

Note that by using this technique, the node only has one transform applied to it; we just update that transform as we progress. Rounding errors still accumulate, but at least the algebra is viable :).

Comment: Sorry to disturb you...but my computer cannot recognize "KeyValue" and "Interpolator" (error: cannot find symbol). Why could this happen...

Comment: Check you have imported them: `import javafx.animation.KeyValue;` and `import javafx.animation.Interpolator;`. (Or in Eclipse, just do Ctrl-Shift-O.)

Comment: Thank you for your help~  The moving trajectory of target is the combination of the "rotation" and the "moveAndScale" (I modified the description of my question. So sorry that I forgot to show this). I tried to update the "KeyValue" to describe this complex trajectory, but did not work... Could you please let me know this?

Comment: Yes, that gets a bit ugly. Are you really meaning to rotate about the x-axis (which is a three-dimensional operation), instead of the z-axis (which is effectively two-dimensional)?